# Iterating Through Redis Keys

Tags: python, json, loops, redis

Currently I have some data stored in Redis which looks like the following

'key:A:1' : 'some_data'
'key:A:2' : 'some_data'
'key:A:3' : 'some_data'
'key:A:4' : 'some_data'
'key:A:5' : 'some_data'
'key:A:6' : 'some_data'

'key:B:7' : 'some_data'
'key:B:8' : 'some_data'
'key:B:9' : 'some_data'
'key:B:10' : 'some_data'
'key:B:11' : 'some_data'
'key:B:12' : 'some_data'

'key:ABC:15' : 'some_data'
'key:ABC:16' : 'some_data'
'key:ABC:17' : 'some_data'
'key:ABC:18' : 'some_data'
'key:ABC:19' : 'some_data'
'key:ABC:20' : 'some_data'

...

... tons of other data that does **not** match the above format

In Python, I want to iterate over all of the keys in the above format (key:*:*) and extract the values. So basically I want to first iterate through all keys of the format key:A:*, then all of the keys of format key:B:* etc. Is there a way to do this without using the `KEYS` pattern? Or should I rethink how I am storing data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command with a match pattern to achieve this. It iterates the keys space in an incremental iteration way, and doesn't block Redis for a long time.

However, this command also has some drawbacks. For example, a given key might be returned multiple times, you should take care it in your client code. See [the documentation](http://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees) for more details.